# Can't upload images to Facebook App

Tags: facebook, lumia-640-xl, uploading

I have Microsoft Lumia 640 XL DS with Windows 8.1 Denim Update. I can't upload images to Facebook as a status update through the Facebook Native app.

After I select the image and submit the upload process stuck in 0% for forever.

How can I fix it? Or it's a bug in Facebook app itself? I tried everything from Soft reset to a hard reset as It's a new phone.

Edit: I'm using the Facebook version 8.3.10.0 created by Microsoft Corporation.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno which app you used, but there are two new Fb oficial apps by Facebook Inc. available on store. In total , there are **4** Facebook apps in store.

- [Facebook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/facebook/9wzdncrfhv5g) by Microsoft Corp.
- [Facebook beta](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/facebook-beta/9wzdncrfj3pk) by Microsoft Corp.
- [Facebook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/facebook/9wzdncrfj2wl) by Facebook Inc. &
- [Facebook (Beta)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/app/9nblggh6ct0l?tduid=(6307352b123d25e873e4520f186619f4)(235158)(2804593)()()) by Facebook Inc.

Give 'em a try!

Comment: Okay. But please check my edited question.

Comment: Fb by MS is outdated, please use the apps by Facebook Inc, and try again!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find any other apps in MS Store named Facebook than the one created by Microsoft Inc. in my device, [Microsoft Lumia 640 XL Dual Sim](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/phone/lumia640-xl-dual-sim/). The listed apps are for Windows 8+ desktop it seems.

Comment: all 4 of 'em are available on windows 10 mobile, thought it will be available for 8.1 too, sry!

Comment: did u search for them or used those above links ,btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42469/discussion-between-ravimallya-and-ram-raj).